# Model Name Not Showing in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm building a simple trivia app and am using bootstrap generators for my forms. In the new and update forms for my models, the model names aren't showing up in my views.  Here's the code for `app/views/questions/new.html.erb`:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <%=t '.title', :default => [:'helpers.titles.new', 'New %{model}'], :model => @model_name %>
  </h1>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

Here's my `questions_controller.rb`:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def new
    @model_name = Question.model_name.human
    @question = Question.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @question }
    end
  end

  ...

  private
    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

The word `New` shows up in the view, but not the model name...
Anyone know what's going on here?

FWIW I tried this with 2.0 and 1.9.3 with the same results.

Comment: If you really want to define variables in the view you can do `<% @model_class = 'Question' %>`

Comment: I tried that and got `undefined local variable or method 'model_class'`

Comment: Shouln't `'New %{model}'` be `"New #{@model_name}"` instead?

Comment: @kiddorails just tried that - no dice.

Comment: Even if I replace `%{model}` with just 'Question', I still only get `New` in the view...

Comment: You were using single quotes and not double. Check my answer :)

Comment: Added a .yml file to show what is needed here.

Comment: @CharlesJHardy I'm probably going to accept this answer, but I'm waiting to hear back from Seyhun, the guy that maintains the gem.  I just want to see if there's a way I can avoid editing every view generated in the future.

Comment: Check my Github account and pop me an email if you want Bro..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining things in the view is a very bad idea. If you have to do this then move it up into the controller.

```
# app/controllers/questions_controller.rb

class QuestionsController < ActionController::Base
  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end
end

# config/locales/questions/en.yml

helpers:
  titles:
    new: new %{model}

# app/views/questions/new.html.erb

<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%= I18n.t('helpers.titles.new', model: @question.class.human) %></h1>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you about defining things in the view and have moved it into the controller, but I still don't get the model name in the view and there are no errors.

Comment: Am i missing something here? shouldn't it be `<h1><%=t '.title', :default => [:'helpers.titles.new', "New %{@model_name}"], :model => @model_name %></h1>`

Comment: It's `[..., "New %{foo}], :foo => @bar ...` Doesn't really matter what goes in there. The issue seems to be with the `helpers.title.new`. I took that out and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the helper and it works.  Not sure why, but here is the final code:

```
<div class="page-header">
   <h1><%=t '.title', :default => 'New %{model_name}', :model_name => @model_name %></h1>
</div>
<%= render :partial => 'form' %>
```